# PHP variable not rendering in IFrame

Tags: php, iframe, widget, stylesheet

This seems like a silly thing, but I have been banging my head against the wall so I thought I'd ask here

I have this code:

```
<?php
    echo '<iframe style="width:<?php echo $width; ?>px;height:100%"  src="hike_widget.php?hike_id='.$hike_id.'&height='.$height.'&width='.$width.'" >
    </iframe>';
?>
```

And if I do a view source on that, it shows this:

```
<iframe style="width:<?php echo $width; ?>px;height:100%" src="hike_widget.php?hike_id=108&height=450&width=450" > 
</iframe>
```

Which is weird because on the same line, the same PHP variable renders correctly, and right next to it in the style snippet, it just renders as text.   Any idea why this is happening?  Thanks!

Comment: I thought it was blink to make the code readable :) ..oopsss..what should I have done?

Comment: use the "code" button after highlighting the code.

Comment: [.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364944/php-variable-not-rendering-in-iframe)..what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '<iframe style="width:' . $width . 'px;height:100%" src="hike_widget.php?hike_id='.$hike_id.'&height='.$height.'&width='.$width.'" ></iframe>';
```

Answer (score 4):

This line doesn't make sense:

```
echo '<iframe style="width:<?php echo $width; ?>px;height:100%"  src="hike_widget.php?hike_id='.$hike_id.'&height='.$height.'&width='.$width.'" >
```

PHP doesn't work that way; you can't nest `<?php` tags.

Instead, you should be closing your string and passing `$width` to the echo statement. The line should look like this:

```
<?php
echo '<iframe style="width:', $width, 'px;height:100%" src="hike_widget.php?hike_id=', $hike_id, '&height=', $height, '&width=', $width, '" >';
?>
```

Comment: I havent touched PHP in a while but comma (,) can be  used for string concatenation? I thought you were supposed to use periods (.) hmmm

Comment: @moe It's not string concatenation, it's a list of arguments to `echo`. It might look more familiar written `echo($a, $b)`, but because `echo` is a language construct and not a true function, you can omit the brackets and write `echo $a, $b`.

Comment: @moe Practically there is no difference between `echo $a, $b` and `echo $a . $b`, except the first way avoids string concatenation which is generally quite expensive. Of course, there is no real sense to this sort of optimization in PHP, but avoiding unnecessary string concatenation is a good habit to get into anyways.